# what happens if looping within several list but one is empty in Scala for

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a Scala loop like:

```
for {
         players <- Players.getAll(p => p.age > 4)
         salaries <- Salaries.getAll(s => s.amount > 30000)
    }yield {
           /*other stuff to do*/
            ....      
    }
```

what happens is just one of   **players**   or   **salaries**   is empty? will the code at  **other stuff to do**  be executed? Will the loop just not be executed?

what happens

Comment: No, for comprehension is sequential, if any of the collections will be empty, then `yield` block will never be executed. In your case `for` will return an empty collection.

Comment: Then it is like exist and AND in between the expressions  that contain   <-

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I had some problems debugging my code and something was telling me this was happening. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reformat your code to be more clear:

```
val pIn = Players.getAll(p => p.age > 4)
val sIn = Salaries.getAll(s => s.amount > 30000)

for {
     players <- pIn
     salaries <- sIn
}yield {
       /*other stuff to do*/
        ....      
}
```

It translated into

```
pIn.flatMap(players => sIn.flatMap(salaries => { /*other stuff to do*/...}))
```

We know that

> `flatMap` works applying a function that returns a sequence for each element in the list, and flattening the results into the original list.

No list elements - no applying function. It means that `/*other stuff to do*/` code will not run in the case of `pIn` or `sIn` is empty

**Attention** 
`pIn` or `sIn` is empty. This is important. If `players` or `salaries` is empty then `/*other stuff to do*/` will work.

this will not work:

```
val pIn = List.empty
val sIn = List(1,2,3)
```

This will work:

```
val pIn = List(List.empty)
val sIn = List(1,2,3)
```